# Issue with inline-block elements with unknown width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to line up two elements in a header:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="title"><h1>This is the title row</h1></div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. </p>
</div>
```

To the left is a fixed width icon, and I want to the title to fill up the remaining width. (The title is broken in two lines because of the narrow columns):

```
.col-md-3 {
    width: 200px; /*this width is just for illustrating the problem, in reality this is Bootstrap's 25% width column*/
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I can't get them to line up using inline-block. Any ideas why?

[PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/PVEZMadBwzxqdKPrIHEP/preview)

**UPDATE**

I added a new plunker (see above) to better demonstrate the problem.

I'm looking for an explanation why inline-block doesn't work in this case, and a possible solution how to make it work. Any workarounds posted are really appreciated, but I'd really like to find out what's the deal with inline-blocks in this case.

Comment: If it doesn't fit in the `col-md-3` it doesn't fit. It just means you don't have enough space. What is the size of the container that the `col-md-3` is in?

Comment: There are four col-md-3 columns in a full width row, and yes there is more than enough room for the title (even if it has to break into multiple lines) as the title is not fixed width, I would assume that being an undefined width inline-block element, it should fill up the remaining vertical space, just like a simple block element would.

Comment: Well it should, are you sure you don't have a float somewhere in the code that is overriding the display property?

Comment: Yes, check the new plunker I just made (updated in question)

Comment: One, question: what is your monitor resolution? [Image](http://i.imgur.com/VC9FRWu.png). This image is taken on 1900px window width.

Comment: 1366, just try resizing the window so a line break happens in the title

Comment: The heading is a block element, and it won't break. `word-break` won't really help. The solution could be to put a width in percentages for `.title` and left margin. `.title {
display: inline-block;
width: 70%;
margin-left: 20px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content of the `inline-block` does not fit on a single row, it will try to fit as a whole on the next line. This is different from regular `inline` elements, that most of the time is allowed to wrap to the next line.

You might want to read up on this behaviour at the [W3C specification about the 'normal flow'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow).

Not sure why everyone makes it so complex, why not use a float?

```css
.icon {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.title {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title h1 {
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="title"><h1>This is the title row erg erg erg erg erg erg er</h1></div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: "why not use a float" > because it comes with other issues that need extra CSS to be fixed. That said, the main issue here is using an HTML with no semantic need for it. This icon might be a better candidate for a background image or for the more modern pseudo-content...

Comment: Point taken. A before pseudo element would be best I reckon. I just wasn't sure if the OP was willing to change the html structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could set `.header` as table, and set `.icon` and `.title` as table cell.

**[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjhekkjw/)**

```css
.header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.header .icon, .header .title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.header .icon {
    width: 60px;
}
.header .icon span {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
.header .title h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon"><span></span></div>
        <div class="title"><h1>This is the title row</h1></div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add display property value of just `inline` to `.col-md-3` and adjust as needed, then `inline-block` to both `.icon` and `.title`

```css
.col-md-3 {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon {
 display: inline-block;
 height:50px;
 width: 50px;
    background: red;

}
.title {
 display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
   line-height: 5px;
    left: 70px; /* Width of the icon plus 10px for space */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="title"><h1>This is the title row</h1></div>
 </div>
    <p>This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. </p>
</div>
```

Note: You may need to further adjust it to suit your need.

Comment: I was trying to edit my own answer, however I made the updates on yours accidentally, but I rolled it back to your version quickly, you can make a minor edit if you want (maybe to improve the code formatting slightly), so my edit info won't be shown there, sorry about that. It is a good answer so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the `width` of the `inline-block` element then the default value is `auto`. Then the browser will try to calculate a **shrink-to-fit** width based on the containing blocks width, in your case the `.header` element which bases its width on your `.col-md-3` width. The browser **does not** take into account your `.icon` elements width when calculating the width of your `.title` element. So to get what you want, still using `display: inline-block`, you have to specify a width for your `.title` element.

```
.title {
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

You could also just use `float` on your `.icon` element. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29074267/4116624).

Another way is to use `display: table` for containing block and `table-cell` for child elements as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29064229/4116624).

[From the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width):

> **10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow**
> If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the **shrink-to-fit** width as for floating elements.

...

> Calculation of the **shrink-to-fit** width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm. **Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block** minus the used values of 'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this instead :

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h2>This is the title row</h2>
    <p>This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. This is some content text. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-3 {   width: 200px; }
h2 { position: relative; padding-left: 50px;}
h2::before { content:''; position: absolute; height:50px; width: 50px; left: 0; background: red;}
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcjwaLf3/)

Comment: Yes, good thinking, this is basically what I did in the end, except I had to use glyphicons, so I put an <i> tag within the <h2>, but the same concept. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Well I tried to be inline with your example code, it is also possible to include images or text instead of this red square without any extra (and useless) HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to .title class

```
.title {
    with: calc(100% - 55px);
}
```

where 55px is from the .icon width plus 5px.